# Word-wrap not working in jumbotron bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap jumbotron but the header wont wrap in next line when long text is used. any way to fix it?
[image]

This is what I am using in my html

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
    <p class="lead">Help visualize leadership networks in the Upper Midwest</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: Normal CSS tricks can be used here.. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following on the text that you want to wrap on to the next line.

```
h1 {
     word-wrap:break-word;
 }
```

This will break up the long word at any character though. See the links below for more information.

[mdn doc for word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)
[css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)